# Getting a link from <a href > with regular expression

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I work with JMeter and I need to get a link from the following `<a href>` tag:

```
<a href="/i/info/14259.html" class="ogrLink">Department page</a>
```

So I need a regular expression for getting this result:
`/i/info/14259.html`

I have tried the following regex but not sure if it is correct:

```
i/info/[0-9]*.html
```

Comment: A  regular expression is used to match a "pattern" not a particular string. For your scenario you can simply compare all the href value to a string you want & if it matches fetch that value. Is this what you intend ?

Comment: Please post your attempts, Stack Overflow is not a regex writing service. I would also suggest regex is the wrong tool for this job

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa , I work in JMeter and need to make a regular expression in block "Regular Expression Extractor" to get /i/info/14259.html  as my result.

Comment: @arco444 My attempt was the following expression:
i/info/[0-9]*.html 
But i'm not sure whether it is correct one

Comment: @thatfella16 that regex looks correct to me. Not sure how you're trying to use it. You might need to escape the slashes `/` =~ `\/`

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote. thx

Answer (score 1):

Check the demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/eR2oH3/24
And selected data will be in $1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to extract data from HTML, the best extractor for that is [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor).

CSS/JQuery expression will be as simple as:

> a.ogrLink

And attribute

> href

Answer (score 0):

Below you have the valid expression:

```html
<a href="(.+?)" class="ogrLink">Department page</a>
```

[image: Regular EXpression Extractor]

The reference name is the variable that is storing the link value